# Why am I allowed to call take() on a mutable reference to an iterator?

Tags: rust, reference, iterator, borrowing

I was trying to use `take(n)` on an iterator to do something with the first `n` items, but then do something different (a `for ... in ...` loop) with the remaining items.

In the declaration:

```
fn take(self, n: usize) -> Take<Self>
```

the `self` as first argument tells me that `take()` must be used on an owned value, not a reference (`&self`) or mutable reference (`&mut self`).

The documentation for `by_ref()` says it returns a mutable reference, and

> This is useful to allow applying iterator adaptors while still
> retaining ownership of the original iterator.

It includes an example using `by_ref().take(n)`, and then continuing to use the iterator (just like I wanted).

My question is, why am I allowed to call `take()` on a mutable reference (as opposed to requiring an owned value)?  In other words, shouldn't `take()` have been declared something like:

```
fn take(&mut self, n: usize) -> Take<Self>
```

to make it possible to use it with a mutable reference?

What declaration should I have been looking for that would have told me this was possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust treats `T`, `&T`, and `&mut T` as separate types. Being separate types we can implement different methods for each of them. Example:

```rust
struct Struct;

trait Printable {
    fn print(self);
}

impl Printable for Struct {
    fn print(self) {
        println!("I'm an owned Struct");
    }
}

impl Printable for &Struct {
    fn print(self) {
        println!("I'm a Struct reference");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = Struct;
    let s_ref = &Struct;
    s.print();
    s_ref.print();
}
```

If we desugar the trait method we get:

```rust
fn print(self: Self) { /* implementation */ }
```

Where `Self` is equal to the implementing type, which in the case of `Struct` is:

```rust
fn print(self: Struct) { /* implementation */ }
```

And in the case of `&Struct` is:

```rust
fn print(self: &Struct) { /* implementation */ }
```

So really `self` can be an owned type or an immutable reference or a mutable reference. The reason why you can call `take` on mutable references to `Iterator`s is [because of this generic blanket impl which implements the `Iterator` trait on all mutable references to `Iterator`s](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-13):

```rust
impl<'_, I> Iterator for &'_ mut I where I: Iterator + ?Sized { /* implementation */ }
```

Let's use `vec.into_iter()` as a concrete example. Since it returns `std::vec::IntoIter` which implements `Iterator` we know this implementation of `take` must exist:

```rust
take(self: std::vec::IntoIter, n: usize) -> Take<std::vec::IntoIter> { /* implementation */ }
```

However, we also know that an implementation of `take` for `&mut std::vec::IntoIter` must exist because it would be automatically generated by the generic blanket impl mentioned above, and that implementation's signature would look like this:

```rust
take(self: &mut std::vec::IntoIter, n: usize) -> Take<&mut std::vec::IntoIter> { /* implementation */ }
```

And this why you can call `take` on any mutable reference to any type that implements `Iterator`.